# Interpretation of critical values of KPSS test

Tags: r, unit-root, stationarity

I am using the KPSS test from the R `urca` package.

My result is the following:

```
$resProp.Dwell.3

####################### 
# KPSS Unit Root Test # 
####################### 

Test is of type: tau with 3 lags. 

Value of test-statistic is: 0.3544 

Critical value for a significance level of: 
                10pct  5pct 2.5pct  1pct
critical values 0.119 0.146  0.176 0.216
```

As the KPSS test is in favour, in case of a rejection, for the non-stationarity. I was wondering, how to interprete the P values.

My initial guess is, as the critical values are larger for the 10pct and 5pct level I should reject stationarity.

Is this correct?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should reject the null hypothesis of stationarity as the value of the test statistic is more extreme than the 10%, 5% and 1% critical values (0.3544 > 0.119, 0.3544 > 0.146, 0.3544 > 0.216).

The basic logic of how to reject or not reject a null hypothesis given the test statistic and a few critical values can be found in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162064/interpretation-of-adf-test/164390#164390).